# How to obtain polymorphic behavior with unique pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

Playing around with C++ after a longer break.

I have a `std::vector` of unique pointers to objects through which I iterate, calling a function that takes as argument the base class from which the objects in the `vector` are derived, like so:

```
for (auto const& object : objects)
{
    _process(object);
}
```

where `objects` would be:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Derived>>
```

I would like to understand how would I enforce polymorphic behavior to call the function:

```
_process(std::unique_ptr<Base> base)
```

Comment: You should not try to convert a `unique_ptr<Derived>` to a `unique_ptr<Base>` while looping through the `vector`. The `base` parameter is being passed by value and would take ownership of the pointer away from the `vector`. I would simply change the `base` parameter to a raw `Base*` pointer since `_process()` should not change ownership, and then call it like `_process(object.get())`

Comment: I would use `_process(Base*);` and call `_process(object.get());`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can convert a `unique_ptr<Derived>` to a `unique_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: That said, I don't understand the question. You can't copy a `unique_ptr`, regardless of polymorphism. What's `_process()` and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Barry not without transferring ownership of the pointer

Comment: @remy  That isn't a **copy**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` represents ownership, and therefore can not be copied.

That means that `_process(std::unique_ptr<Base> base)` is a sink, i.e. it consumes the object (it can destroy it or store it somewhere, but the caller has no control over it anymore). In order to call it you'd have to use `std::move`:

```
_process(std::move(object))
```

that way you explicitly reject the ownership over the object and essentially remove it from your container - the pointer will be reset to `nullptr`.

Naturally that can only be done via non-`const` reference.

If you don't want to transfer the ownership and just want to do something with the object - which the name `_process` seem to imply - you're supposed to pass the regular raw pointer:

```
_process(Base* base);
...
for (auto const& object : objects)
{
    _process(object.get());
}
```

Raw pointers are still great for everything except controlling the lifetime of your objects.

In both cases (raw pointer and `unique_ptr`) there should be absolutely no problem with implicitly converting from `Derived` to `Base`.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you consider destruction; virtual dtor or type erased deleter is needed for your code to be correct.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think the question was specifically about the smart pointers, and OP is aware of polymorphic destruction and related issues. I guess I'll add a couple of links just in case.

Comment: It is part of "polymorphic behaviour", esp with a unique ptr.